# Constant pattern in Javascript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, constants, ecmascript-3

How were implemened constants in `javascript` before `ES5` was released?

There were no `get/set` stuff, no `writable` property, no `const` word, no `Object.freeze` stuff as far as I know, so how I could make my own constant, which can't be changed?

Like, as example, `Math.PI`

[image]

Comment: You simply *didn't modify* your variables…? Typically informally "enforced" by using all uppercase names.

Comment: @deceze you sure?

Comment: Functions that return primitive values also prevent accidental overwriting.

Comment: @DanilGholtsman Yes, we're sure.

Comment: If there isn't any such thing as constants, it's up to each individual developer to decide how to work around it. The above is a typical approach, not just for JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How were constant such as `Math.PI` implemented in javascript before ES5 was released?

Even ES3 knew property attributes - see section 8.6.1 in [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf). There were `ReadOnly`, `DontEnum`, `DontDelete` and `Internal`.

In fact, for the `Math.PI` property the spec says "*This property has the attributes { DontEnum, DontDelete, ReadOnly }.*"

However, one could (and still can) overwrite the whole `Math` object with another one.

> How I could make my own constant, which can't be changed?

You could not. There was no way to make variables or objects immutable, for that you needed to wait until ES6 (`const`) and ES5 (`Object.freeze`) respectively.

Developer discipline was all that prevented constants from being overwritting. Often, style guides include standards for them, like all-uppercase names.

Comment: Thank you! Been thinking about it whole day